# Listen for linux command in a Qt app running in background?

Tags: linux, qt

I wonder if there is a way to send data from an OS command (Linux to begin with, but I would be interested about Windows too) to a Qt app working in background.
My use case would be to right click in a context menu in a file explorer and then send the path of the selected file(s) to the already running Qt app to trigger an action inside that app.

Can anyone provide some explanations or a link to an example achieving that ?
I already read about adding right click in Nemo/Nautilus with some custom config files, I am more interested by the Qt part.

Comment: Qt does not have the task of listening to the events on the windows, Qt only listens to the events when the Qt windows has focus. For example Qt cannot listen to the *right click in a context menu in a file explorer* event. For that you have to use the libraries it offers (or better the desktop manager)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such component available with QT. (Don't know if anything added recently, I haven't used qt from long time)

But what you can do is write some code in qt app like server ( May be socket server OR pipe), when some data comes on that you can take action based on that data value.

On other side write some small utility which will get called, which send data to you server, with path of selected file when clicked via context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will search about the use of sockets.

Comment: QLocalSocket may do the trick, but there will be 2 apps, the main running one, and another that will be launched with the right click to forward selected paths to the main one. I will update this post if I succeed, it might help others.

Comment: @cleve21 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-network.html